# Using pool without destroying connection makes system to hang

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

If I deploy this code to Amazon Lambda ...

```
var settings = require('./settings');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: settings.host,
    database: settings.database,
    user: settings.user,
    password: settings.password
});

module.exports.handler = function (request, context, callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function (error, connection) {
        if (error)
            return callback(error);
        connection.query('select 1', null, function (error, results) {
            callback(null, results);
        });
    });
};
```

... endpoint finishes with timeout error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "2017-07-20T10:04:26.629Z cc46e503-6d32-11e7-8fa9-9902efa96cc1 Task timed out after 6.00 seconds"
}
```

If I add **connection.destroy** - this code finishes successfully:

```
...
    connection.query('select 1', null, function (error, results) {
        connection.destroy();
        callback(null, results);
    });
...
```

But I suppose destroying connection is not a good practice.
If I use **connection.release()** instead of **connection.destroy()** - this doesn't help, hangs as in first example.

Comment: did u tried using `connection.release` as specified https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections

Comment: @SukhmeetSingh - I wrote in the original message - yes, doesn't help.

Comment: i think only destroy submits the connection back to the pool. 
`Pages that use connection pooling, on the other hand, maintain open connections in a pool. When the page requires access to the database, it simply uses an existing connection from the pool, and establishes a new connection only if no pooled connections are available.` 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add **context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;** to my handler:

```
module.exports.handler = function (request, context, callback) {
   context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
   ....
```